# Issue due to scope of variable - the value is not changing out the while loop

Tags: unix

```
ScriptPath=$(dirname $0)
Userlist=${ScriptPath}/Config_Userlist.csv

user="hive"
export flag=0
sed 1d $Userlist | while read user_list
do

if [[ "$user_list" != "$user" ]]; then
flag=1
fi
done 

echo $flag
```

If the condition passes `flag` value becomes 1. However when I am getting that variable after the while loop it's again zero. It's not updating the changed value.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes create subshells and subshells cannot modify the variables in their parents.

Instead of using `sed` and piping it to `while` if your shell supports process substitution you could rewrite it as

```
while read user_list do;
    ... # all the same stuff you have in your loop
done < <(sed 1d "$Userlist")
```

and then the `while` will run in the original shell and you can set `flag`

Comment: getting below error: sample.sh: line 16: warning: here-document at line 14 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `sed')
sample.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `1d'
sample.sh: line 16: `done << sed 1d "$Userlist"'

Comment: @sadhana make sure you have a space between the two `<` characters